# Can I Create the same XML file using Struct instead of class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is serialization the best method? And keeping the class name same(transaction) can i change the node name transaction in XML Document. I have Parameter declared in a class

```
public  class transaction //Main Class
{            
    public string propertyID;                  
    public patronInfo TrxPatron;//sub class
    public transactioninfo TrxDetails ;// sub class
}

public  class patronInfo
{
    public string patronID;               
}

public  class transactioninfo
{
    public string Key;                
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    transaction tobj = new transaction();
    patronInfo pobj = new patronInfo();
    transactioninfo tiobj = new transactioninfo();
    tobj.propertyID = "123456";// I add the rest of the values too
    string value= SerializeElement("po.xml", tobj);// save to a file
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(value);//I get the xmlfile as a string i convert it into XMl
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
    Console.Read();  
}

// this is my serialization method i use file to avoid compilation error
public static string SerializeElement(string  filename,object transactiondetails)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(transaction));           
    StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
    ser.Serialize(writer1, transactiondetails);            
    writer1.Close();
    return sww.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can serialize `struct` the same way you do it for `class`.
2. You can change the XML element name using `XmlRoot` attribute:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("MyNewElementName")]
   public  class transaction //Main Class
   {            
       public string propertyID;                  
       public patronInfo TrxPatron;//sub class
       public transactioninfo TrxDetails ;// sub class
   }
   ```

Comment: What if i want to keeping the class name for my sub class same and change the  node names I tried it using Xmlroot they remain the same

Comment: For them, use XmlName on field declaration.